# High CPU and frame rate drop in SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, instruments

I'm making my first game with SpriteKit in which enemies come on the screen from one side and go off screen on the other side. I noticed that later in the game when different types of enemies are being rendered, the FPS drops and the CPU usage approaches 100% (~95-99%). I've used two of the instrument debugging tools with these results:

In the time profiler tool, I found that `main` which I think is the body of the `appDelegate` is the problem.. I know this may seem obvious, but I was surprised to see that functions like `update` in `GameScene` were hardly the problem. Is there a way to dig deeper into this at this? If it was one of my functions causing the problem I feel as though it would be easier to assess where I messed up.

[image]
I also used the allocations tool and found that a large use of memory was going to building new alien sprites:

[image]

This is my code for adding normal aliens:

```
func addNormAlien(){

    let mult = normAlienMultiplers

    let alienInst = normAlien(startPos:CGPoint(x: 10,y: 10), speed: random(UInt32(10),max: UInt32(50))*mult[0])

    let yStart = random(UInt32(alienInst.size.height/2), max: UInt32(size.height-alienInst.size.height))
    alienInst.position = CGPoint(x:size.width+alienInst.size.width/2, y:CGFloat(yStart))

    addChild(alienInst)
    totalNodes+=1
}
```

Is this somewhat expected as it's expensive to keep instantiating new sprites (even though I rarely go over 20 at once)? I only do so to ensure a random spread of them.

I also haven't been able to find much on texture sizes -- is there a convention to use? Currently, I find myself making sprite textures fairly large and then shrinking them down with `setScale` rather than doing so within an image editor.

These textures and animations are also being (*preloaded*?) at the start of my `GameScene` file with lines like

```
let laserTexture = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Sprites").textureNamed("laserTexture")`
```

and

```
let shipFrames = ["ship0","ship1","ship2","ship3","ship4","ship5","ship6","ship7","ship8","ship9","ship9","ship9","ship8","ship7","ship6","ship5","ship4","ship3","ship2","ship1","ship0"].map{textureAtlas.textureNamed($0)}`
```

right before: `class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {`

and are consequently accessed from my Sprite classes with lines like:

```
    super.init(texture: shipStartTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: shipStartTexture.size())
```

and

```
func animateShip1() {
    let animate = SKAction.animateWithTextures(shipFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1)
    let forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animate)
    self.runAction(forever)
}
```

If there is a better way of pre-allocating textures I'd love to know and any further insight about how I could go about assessing some of these other problems would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you will find that main contains the highest CPU usage because often, most things are run from the main thread. You will need to drill down to find the actual offenders, which you have done.  Bear in mind this is all done relative to the run you used with Instruments. So if you do not have enough data points, you can get red herrings. An example of this is game loading. This can be an expensive operation. In some cases it may seem relatively fast (say 1-5 seconds to load), but when you look at your profiling, you may find it consumes a good chunk of time. However, if you find during runtime you have a high FPS, that overhead of that loading is worth it.

Going to your scenario, one question is how long did you run this? Another would be how often is addNormAlien actually called? Is it every frame? Your addNormAlien has 2 parts which are eating up time which is the creation as well as the adding to the hierarchy. Without knowing how Apple has implemented these items, they are effectively a bit of a blackbox, but it is clear there are aspects to creation that are expensive. Again, not knowing the temporal qualities of your game makes this hard to fully peg down. Going back to what I had mentioned earlier, if all this work is done during loading, then these numbers can be a red herring. So you need to ensure your test run is representative enough of a play session.

One recommendation would be to create an existing pool of already constructed aliens nodes. Then pull a object from the pool when you need it (BTW, you probably should include your normAlien method too). This is BTW, how many games do it. They create pre-allocated versions of items they are going to need during runtime based on the premise of using the load time to incur the "penalty" of object creation, keeping runtime relatively free of that overhead. Note there is a trick to this however. You will need to do some minimal initialization when pulling a free object from the pool. Previously you would have been relying on the constructor/initializer. But since this is an already created object, you will not have that luxury (remember you're trying to remove unnecessary overhead whilst running). This means you do need to be vigilant about it as it can create some difficult bugs to track otherwise.

The other thing, which I mentioned in that other posting you had would be to disable things. For example there is a runAction happening where the copy looks expensive.

Regarding texture size. How large is large? In general, that is a bad idea. You are incurring penalties by doing this. However, depending on how large is large, where you are scaling, etc, the overhead could be negligible. An easy test is to run a version where the texture is the right size versus the large one. There is no reason to use the large one if you are always scaling down.

Anyways, there are numerous things here to look into which is why game performance tuning can be tricky as well as why there approach for one game may not be applicable to another. Only you know then nuances of how you built it.

### Added Info based question update.

Regarding your updates to your question. It seems to me you are expanding the scope now to unrelated items (preloading textures) and are also looking for a silver bullet or one stop answer to all your woes. There is none. As mentioned, remedying these types of things can be tricky and highly game dependent. Only you know your game and only you can run it in Instruments. There are strategies one uses. Much of this comes about with experience and some question asking (eg. why is initializing taking so long?). If this leads to more SO questions, then break off the question.

Regarding preloading textures, you will need to either create a new question for that. Think of a loading screen you see in so many games. Why do you think they exist? To load things in the background like textures and other data. Yes, it adds dev complexity, but it is needed to provide a better experience for the user. The preload is done via `preload`. What you are referencing in your code snippets is just initialization of data which can be used later to reference the texture instances.

What I suggest you do is find ways to isolate parts of code to determine where your performance hit is from. For example you've checked node count. 20 is not very large. PI would be surprising that dynamically creating them would have such overhead, but your time profiling does indicate there may be some significant overhead. If the init overhead is indeed large, you could measure it by simply making your game just allocate new aliens every frame. You should probably be able to run for a few seconds without running out of memory. You can then use that to start to remove parts of code to see how that impacts performance. You should hopefully see here that much of this does become trial and error. No silver bullet/set answer and it takes a certain mindset to be good at optimizing.

I mentioned this in one of your other questions, but if you are doing this on the simulator, it is not the right way to tune performance. It must be done on the device.

Comment: I just updated my post with my preallocation of textures- hopefully this is the correct method? Also I believe the `runAction`  is animation of textures sprites. I was also curious about how I'd create that "pool" of existing objects? Would I not be able to give them varying coordinates/speeds at that point? Or would I construct them and assign those properties after? And is there a way to go about doing this preloading while running some basic animation? When loading the sprites before the game starts everything freezes and the fadeIn animation to `GameScene` doesn't run.

Comment: Also `addNormAlien` Is called once every 1-2 seconds and this was run for about 5 minutes.

Comment: Something has to be wrong then, If you only call it 1-2 seconds, I would not expect that much impact unless your addNormAlien is inordinately CPU intensive. I added some more info in my answer.